# Align divs to left and right edges of parent div using float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want `#first` to be aligned to the left of `#container` and `#second` to the right.
For this, I'm using `float: left;` on `#first` and `float: right;` on `#second`.
This, however, results in `#first` aligning left of the `#container` and `#second` just next to it. Why is this the case, and how can I achieve what I desire?

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Here's my code:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        #first {
            float: left;
        }

        #second {
            float: right:
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="first">
            <p>first</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p>second</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, well. No need to create an `:after`-property for containing the floats, just use `overflow: hidden;` on the container.

```html
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid #000;
overflow: hidden;
        }

        #first {
            float: left;
        }

        #second {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="first">
            <p>first</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p>second</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd like know why `overflow: hidden;` works and causes the height of `#container` to restore. Can you help me with that?

Comment: There are reasons, of course. You can read this article, it explains most methods: https://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong. First of all you have a colon instead of semicolon near:

```
#second {
    float: right: // <- change ':' to ';'
}
```

After you fix that you have to clear the content since both divs (#first and #second) are floated which causes container to have 0 height. You can achieve that using the following style:

```
#container:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

See demo:

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#container:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
#first {
  float: left;
}
#second {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    <p>first</p>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <p>second</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: junkfoodjunkie, in his answer, proposed a simpler style to restore the height of  `#container`. Is there any downside to using it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that #container is positioned relatively, we could do this to get the result you want:

```
    #container {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    #first {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        height:100%;
    }

    #second {
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        height:100%;
    }
```

Your current css is not working because float:right and float:left simply determine how the DOM elements interact with their siblings; Not their parents.  If you wants the children divs of #first and #second to not fill the parent div you can also change height property on them to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough, this also sometimes does the trick.

```
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#first {
  float: right;
}

#second {
  float: right:
}

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="first">
            <p>goes right</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p>goes left</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```